# Laravel 5 Search in Multi attributes

Tags: php, laravel, search, laravel-5

I`m new to the laravel 5.4 and i need to create a multi attribute search.i can only do the search for a single attribute.but i cannot find out the right way to do so.

here is the search field i want.
[image]

Here is the view related to it.

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <label>Select Your Institute</label> -->
        <label>Search By</label>
        <select name="institute" id="institute">
            <option selected="selected" value="Trainee Id">Trainee Id</option>
            <option value="Trainee Name">Trainee Name</option>
            <label for="Search">Name</label>
        </select>

        <form action="search" method="post" class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="search" />
            <br>
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
</div>
```

Here is the Controller which i need the modification for above view specially in drop down.

```
public function search_code(Request $request){
    $query = $request->search;
    $customers = DB::table('registerdetails')->where('id', 'LIKE',"%$query%")->get();
    return view('registeredusers.index')->with('customers',$customers);
}
```

Can anyone suggest me the controller which i select from the drop down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the select drop down in your `<form>`, so you can retrieve it with `$request->institute` in your controller. Then based on the value of dropdown chosen (either id or name), do a query.

```
<form action="search" method="post" class="form-inline">

  <select name="institute" id="institute">
    <option selected="selected" value="id">Trainee Id</option>
    <option value="name">Trainee Name</option>
    <label for="Search">Name</label>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="search" /><br>
  <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

In your controller:

```
public function search_code(Request $request){
    $query = $request->search;
    $queryType = $request->institute; // 'id' or 'name'
    $customers = DB::table('registerdetails');        

    if($queryType == 'id'){
      $customers = $customers->where('id', 'LIKE',"%$query%");
    }
    if($queryType == 'name'){
      $customers = $customers->where('name', 'LIKE',"%$query%");
    }
    $customers->get();

    return view('registeredusers.index')->with('customers',$customers);

}
```

Comment: Sir ,i changed these, so it shows error called "Undefined variable: customers" in my controller.how can i fixed it?

Comment: Code updated to add in initialisation of `$customers`, take note that I also updated the <option value>

Comment: Now its ok but here is another error. sir can you please take look at why this "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$full_name (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Training_Management\resources\views\registeredusers\index.blade.php)"

Comment: full_name means attribute of search instead of just name.